# Inserting html with jquery and modernizr

Tags: jquery, html, debugging, modernizr

New to Modernizr and jQuery but thought this would work based on examples I've seen. The Modernizr and jQuery scripts are loaded and this is lower down in the page:

```
<div id="demo></div>
<script>
(function() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 500px)')) {
        $('div.demo').html('test');
    }
});
</script>
```

So what exactly am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
$(function() {
if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 500px)')) {
$('div#demo').html('test');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. What would I need to add to this snippet to have it refire if someone resizes their browser?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
$('div#demo')
```

`#` indicates an ID.

`.` indicates a class.

Comment: Or to add the `class=demo` to the div.  Also the div has an unclosed quotation on the id

Comment: @lucuma - yes or that.  Both would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `$` for your jQuery code, should be:

```
$(function()
```

as well as you specify `id` for your div so you need to use `#` instead of `.`:

```
$('div#demo')
```